# Data Structure in Scala for a Recursive data type

Tags: scala, recursion

Goal here is to do some URL Parsing and checking. I start with a single URL, called the base URL, I call this URL and I parse the HTML, extract the URL'S found in this base URL, for each URL found, I repeat the same process. I control how deep I want to go based on the depth parameter!

So for this, I have a recursive structure that goes like this:

I start with a single element, do some operation and the result is a Sequence of elements. I will have then to iterate over this Sequence of elements where for each of this element, I end up getting another Sequence of elements. I then repeat the same process to iterate over each element and get the Sequence for each. I control how depth I want to go based on the depth parameter (an integer).

Here is a simplified version:

```
  def getElemsFor(url: String): List[String] = {
    //(browser.get(url) >> elementList("a[href]") >?> attr("href")).flatten
    List("1", "2")
  }

  def parse(depth: Int, elems: List[String]): List[String] = {
    elems.flatMap(elem => {
      if (depth > 0) {
        parse(depth - 1, getElemsFor(elem))
      } else elems
    })
  }
```

As it can be seen that I'm actually dealing with URL's, but for simplicity, I'm using simple Strings for testing purposes where I want to have a firm recursion scheme for what I'm  trying to do. Now when I ran my program like this:

```
parse(1, getElemsFor("1"))
```

I get the following as result:

```
res17: List[String] = List("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2")
```

I then took a paper and pen and worked out what I actually expect for this input as can be seen below:

```
base depth 1
1     1
      2
2     1
      2
```

So overall, I should have only 6 elements as result as per what I expect, but I get this additional 2 elements that I do not get from where it comes. I know that I'm making a simple mistake somewhere. Any help?

I could do this to get to my actual result, but is there a better way?

```
parse(1, getElemsFor("1")) diff getElemsFor("1")
```

Comment: The result is expected. 

1 -> recur on (1, 2) -> map -> (1, 2, 1, 2)
2 -> recur on (1, 2) -> map -> (1, 2, 1, 2)

You start with 2 elements, turn them into 4 elements when you recur for the first time, after which each element gets mapped to 2 elements giving you the total of 8

Comment: Is that correct what I'm doing?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are trying to do but your pen and paper calculation is wrong here. You should be getting back 8 things. I am not sure what getting 6 things back map to

Comment: I'm trying to recurse over a data structure that I build based on the results I get. So I start with a single element and when I run a function on this element, I get a sequence of elements. This is the first depth. I then check if I have to go further (check if depth > 0), if yes, I take the result of the first run which is a sequence, for each element in the sequence, I run the same function again which results in a Sequence for each elements. I guess I have mentioned this clearly in my post above.

Comment: the code is correct for that explanation. I am confused about why you expected this to return 6 elements. This creates a recursion tree that expands by 2 at every depth for each element so the end length is guaranteed to be a power of 2

Comment: I have added a bit more context to my original post! Take a look and may be it explains why. I'm starting to think that it is correct what I did and yes, 8 elements are indeed correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230466/discussion-between-sinanspd-and-joesan).